# Показать элемент массива в другом компоненте по клику на него react.js

Tags: массивы, reactjs

вот основной компонент:

```
function NotesContainer() {
  const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const onChange = useCallback(() => setIsDisplayed(!isDisplayed), [
    isDisplayed,
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {data.map((item, key) => (
          <Notes
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            date={item.date}
            key={key}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <DisplayNote isShow={isDisplayed} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

это компонент с заметками:

```
const Notes = ({ title, description, date, onChange, key }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem button onClick={onChange} key={key}>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <div className={[styles.item, styles.title].join(" ")}>{title}</div>
        <div className={[styles.item, styles.description].join(" ")}>
          {description}
        </div>
        <div className={[styles.item, styles.date].join(" ")}>{date}</div>
      </div>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

а это блок, где должен показываться description той заметки, на кликнет юзер

```
const DisplayNote = ({ isShow }) => {
  const [isShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.showBlock}>
      {isShow && (
        <>
          {data.map((item, key) => (
            <div key={key}>{item.description}</div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Сейчас, по клику на элемент, у меня показывается выводятся ВСЕ дескрипшены. А нужно, чтоб толкьо один именно того элемента, на котором был клик. Плюс, сейчас на первый жлемент если кликнуть, то выводятся все дескрипены,на следующий кликаю - они все исчезают.
Помогити, пожалуйста!!
Понимаю, что я не праильно маплю данные.
Но я не мог уразобраться, в чем дело(((

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в о том, что вы показываете всю дату, а не конкретную запись

Простым решением может быть передача индекса нужной записи в функцию onChange, и вывод конкретной записи по индексу в DispalyNot

Также вот немного ревью, не благодарите

```
const DisplayNote = ({ isShow }) => {
  const [isShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.showBlock}>
      {isShow && (
        <>
          {data.map((item, key) => (
            <div key={key}>{item.description}</div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Строчка с **const [isShow] = useState(false);** здесь не имеет смысла

**isShow** вы принимаете из **Props**

Также непонятно откуда вы получаете **data**

**Data** должна получаться из **props** или из **hook**, для того что-бы React мог корректно отлавливать изменения состония этой переменной

```
function NotesContainer() {
  const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const onChange = useCallback(() => setIsDisplayed(!isDisplayed), [
    isDisplayed,
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {data.map((item, key) => (
          <Notes
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            date={item.date}
            key={key}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <DisplayNote isShow={isDisplayed} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

В этой строчке, лучше всего переименуйте переменную, например на **handleChangeShowNot**

Так как onChange совсем не говорит что вы меняете
const onChange = useCallback(() => setIsDisplayed(!isDisplayed), [
isDisplayed,
]);